# App crash while creating tables until SQLite database name or version is changed

Tags: android, sqlite

Whenever I try to run my project second time (doesnt matter if I change anything or not), I end up getting a crash. If I change the db name or version, the application starts working again.

As far as I have understood (I am new to Android Development), that after you do getWritableDatabase() the database is actually created. After that, if the database is created for the first time, the onCreate method is called in the helper class, otherwise onUpgrade is called (please correct me on the last phrase). Now my OnCreate and OnUpgrade are fairly simple:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TOI);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HINDU);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NEWSPAPER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NEWSPAPER_CATEGORY);

            Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate MySQLhelper");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all data");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TOI);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_HINDU);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NEWSPAPER);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORY);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NEWSPAPER_CATEGORY);
            onCreate(db);

    }
```

After the getWritableDatabase command in my DAO class, I call a class Tables where I use SQLiteStatement to preload the tables. This is where the app crashes. From the logcat, the error being "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)".

I dont remember where but I read somewher on StackOverflow regarding a problem (I dont remember the problem either), the answer was to change the database name and try, and it had worked for OP. I tried the same and it worked for me.

So now, I have to change the database name or number for every run.

My Files:

[Logcat](http://pastebin.com/2mZ94JKB)

[Tables.java](http://pastebin.com/vsNysxzN)

[MySQLiteHelper.java](http://pastebin.com/L3zLixrV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you create an instance of `Tables`, you are inserting data into the database. This does not make much sense in general -- probably you want to move that logic into `onCreate()` of you `MySQLiteHelper` class.

If for some reason you really *do* want to insert data every time you create an instance of `Tables`, you need to use unique values for your `PRIMARY KEY` columns. Your current code tries to insert `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` each time for your four rows. That will work the first time, but the second time, those rows are already there, and so you get the unique-constraint violation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark(?), apparently I was just reading your book to find some clue. moving the new instance line to onCreate sounds good. 

The tables are just "static", they are something to refer to by other variables. They (would) just contain some urls and some strings as a store. They would only be created when the app is ran for the first time by the user.

Comment: @iWantToCode: "They would be created when the app is ran for the first time by the user" -- all the more reason to move that logic to `onCreate()` of your `MySQLiteHelper`. Note that you won't need your own transaction there, as `onCreate()` already runs inside of a transaction.

Comment: "you won't need your own transaction there" by this you mean that I wouldn't need to use database.beginTransaction(); and the following commands? Just a direct call to createTableNewspaper(); etc?

Comment: @iWantToCode: You won't need the `beginTransaction()`/`endTransaction()`/`markTransactionAsSuccessful()` calls. You'll still need to do your inserts, of course -- Android's good, but mind-reading isn't slated to be released until Glass becomes publicly available and can start inserting microscopic tendrils into users' brains. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I think it is working now. What I did is: added new Tables(db) in the onCreate after all the db.execSQL commands. In the Tables constructor, I just called the methods to create the tables, no other line.

public Tables(SQLiteDatabase database) {

  createTableNewspaper();
  createTableCategory();
  createTableNewsCat();

 }

Comment: Can you please also comment about this "...if the database is created for the first time, the onCreate method is called in the helper class, otherwise (if db is already created) onUpgrade is called..."?

Comment: @iWantToCode: Ummm... I don't know what you want me to comment on. `onUpgrade()` is called if you bump your schema version number, and the database already exists with an older schema version number.

Comment: oh sorry to be vague. I meant "if I rerun an application, is the database created again or the database from previous run is retained? If latter, is onCreate called?"

Comment: @iWantToCode: A database is only deleted if the user uninstalls the app, or the user clicks "Clear Data" in the app's page in Settings, or you arrange to delete it. Otherwise, it will be there from run to run of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lote Mark, I appreciate all the help. :)